# I don't understand some parts of the code

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to understand a code from a programming site. This is not very well explained and I have not found the necessary answers.

So..What does it mean `val[0] == '\'' and x[0] == '\"'`?

Comment: You should take a look at [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

Comment: In string and character literals you have to escape certain characters to enter them.

Comment: @john no, it compares if val[0] is equal to ' and if x[0] is equal to ".

Comment: @Unterfliege My bad, I misread.

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's C, you can't use `and` as a replacement for `&&` unless you have `#include <iso646.h>`. Also, the title on your question doesn't tell anyone what you're asking about, and you haven't told us what it is about the expression that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char a = '\'';
    std::string b = "\"";
    std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b=" << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The out put will be:

```
a='
b="
```

As the comments indicate this is the only way escape the `'` and `"` characters. you can ignore `[0]` as that just indicates it's an array of chars and your accessing the first ones.

Comment: " does not need to be escaped between ''

Comment: _is the only way escape the ' and " characters_ Better: is **a** way to escape... It could also be done using an octal sequence (e.g. `'\033'`), or hexadecimal sequence (e.g. `'\x1b'`) for example. Though, `'\''` and `"\""` are surely the **easiest** way to escape quote characters. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As other's have mentioned the backslash is used escape certain characters.

To illustrate why we need escape characters, look at the example below:

```
if(val[0] == ''' && x[0] == '"'){

}
```

To a person the intention is clear, but to a compiler this is ambiguous.

The compiler will first try to extract tokens from your program like so:

if => IF

(  => (

val => IDENTIFIER

[ => [

0 => INTEGER

] => ]

== => EQ_OP

'' => CONSTANT

'&& x[0] == ' => CONSTANT

"'){} => Here it fails. Either the tokenizer sees the ", tries to match a string literal but the tokenizer prevents having an unescaped single quote in a string, and therefore doesn't match anything... causing an error. Option two, the tokenizer
doesn't complain about the unescaped single quote, as " must having a closing ", and therefore does not find a match.